# please help find a good function to map reduced residues to cyclic group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Is there a function that maps a reduced residue system to a product of cyclic groups?

What is the function mapping a reduced residue system modulo $3 \times$ prime number(5,7,11,...) to a cyclic group?

$x_{3p} \in$ reduced residue system modulo $3p$ (p is a prime number)

(i,j)  where $i \in ℤ/2ℤ$ and $j \in ℤ/p-1ℤ$

$x_{15} \equiv (i,j)$ where $x_{15} = (-1)^i \cdot 2^j$ modulo 15

$x_{21} \equiv (i,j)$ where $x_{21} = (-1)^i \cdot 2^j$ modulo 21

$x_{33} \equiv (i,j)$ where $x_{33} = (-1)^i \cdot 5^j$ modulo 33

$x_{39} \equiv (i,j)$ where $x_{39} = (-1)^i \cdot 2^j$ modulo 39

$x_{51} \equiv (i,j)$ where $x_{51} = (-1)^i \cdot 5^j$ modulo 51

$x_{57} \equiv (i,j)$ where $x_{57} = (-1)^i \cdot 5^j$ modulo 57

$x_{69} \equiv (i,j)$ where $x_{69} = (-1)^i \cdot 2^j$ modulo 69

$x_{93} \equiv (i,j)$ where $x_{69} = (-1)^i \cdot 13^j$ modulo 93

$x_{129} \equiv (i,j)$ where $x_{69} = (-1)^i \cdot 14^j$ modulo 129

Is there any pattern for the base of the power?

Comment: Not sure what you are hoping for.  Your question is in the same spirit as asking for a primitive root $\pmod p$, and nobody has any idea what a general solution to that might look like.

Comment: thank you... but not all the primitive roots work. For example, when p=31, among the primitive roots 3, 11, 12, 13, 17, 21, 22, and 24, only 13 and 22 works.

Comment: I didn't say it was exactly the same problem, I said it was in the same spirit.  You need to get half of your elements out of powers of your base.  I see no reason to imagine that this is a simpler problem.

Comment: In particular, if the modulus were $p$ instead of $3p$, then what you're asking for is exactly the "discrete logarithm problem". (But if you had such a function, the extension from $p$ to $3p$ is trivial, thanks to the Chinese remainder theorem.)

Comment: thank you. that worked... any primitive roots of p that are equivalent to 1 modulo 3 work. If the primitive root is equivalent to 2 modulo 3, then make it 1 modulo 3 by adding p's.